# rendering images in background

Tags: uitableview, image-processing, calayer, grand-central-dispatch, nscache

i have a tableview which is not that complex with 5-6 subviews, but the imageview renders high res images in it, which show in a 200X174 sized imageview. The images are being downloaded asychronously and being cache to disk. But, as the user scrolls through the tableview, thereis a stutter in scroll when the scroll is about to settle down. I wish to make my own custom cell, that does the drawing using calayers by overriding the drawrectmethod. Is it possible to render those images in an async backgroud queue so that user has a smooth scrolling experience?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is use Instruments to figure out what the problem really is. So far it sounds like you're just guessing. It isn't even clear from your question whether the problem is the downloading or the drawing. Watch the WWDC 2012 video on this topic as well; they talk a lot about the problem of getting a smooth table scrolling experience. There could be lots of other things about your cell that's causing the problem. You might be able to solve it just by rasterizing, for example. Your question gives no detail on how you're drawing and where the delay really is, so there's little point guessing.

Comment: yes, i wish to do that. but being an absolute beginner, i am not finding the apple's documentation on instruments to be easy enough for me. how do i go about using instruments to cpu profile my app while I am scrolling the tableview?

Comment: As I said, watch the WWDC 2012 video. They show you exactly how to do it.